# How do I prevent jQuery from adding an extra space ' ' in insertAfter function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, insertafter

This insertion code works just fine

```
<script>
    var X = 0;
    $(function () {
            X++;
            $("#AddNumber").on({ 'click': function () { $('<div class="form-row"><label><span>Another Number</span><input type="tel" name="Mobile' + X + '"><a><img onclick="$(this).closest("div").remove();" class="DeleteNumber" width="25" height="25" src="/Images/Delete.png" /></a></label></div>').insertAfter("#AddNumberAction"); } });
        }
    );

</script>
```

But when I check it after inserting its like this

[image: Inspect Element on Google Chrome]

which is making it not working properly..

Comment: `onclick="$(this).closest("div").remove();"` looks funky - anyway, jQuery doesn't add spurious spaces - something you've done is doing that

Comment: it should to be `onclick="$(this).closest('div').remove();"` but i can't do that since i should write the code as

`<script>
    var X = 0;
    $(function () {
            X++;
            $("#AddNumber").on({ 'click': function () { $('<div class="form-row"><label><span>Another Number</span><input type="tel" name="Mobile' + X + '"><a><img onclick="$(this).closest('div').remove();" class="DeleteNumber" width="25" height="25" src="/Images/Delete.png" /></a></label></div>').insertAfter("#AddNumberAction"); } });
        }
    );

</script>`
because the main quotations are '

Comment: What space are you referring to? The HTML display in your image is a formatted display, so it pretties the code with line breaks and spaces. The original HTML markup is long gone.

Comment: I don't think that am putting it in the right words

The problem is with the quotation marks ' and "

in the inserted Img the "onclick" event has the same kind of quotation mark as the "div"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is about quote usage...

The argument passed to `.closest()` is passed using double quotes. But double quotes already are wrapping the `onclick=` string...

Since the whole jQuery element group you are creating is already wrapped using single quotes... Then, you should use an escaped set of single quotes around `div`... Like `<img onclick="$(this).closest(\'div\').remove();"`

So try like this:

```
<script>
  var X = 0;
  $(function () {
    X++;
    $("#AddNumber").on({ 'click': function () { $('<div class="form-row"><label><span>Another Number</span><input type="tel" name="Mobile' + X + '"><a><img onclick="$(this).closest(\'div\').remove();" class="DeleteNumber" width="25" height="25" src="/Images/Delete.png" /></a></label></div>').insertAfter("#AddNumberAction"); } });
  });

</script>
```